# Issue with dual graphics cards, inconsistency between different system information

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop which is a Lenovo U31. This laptop has both an Intel Integrated Graphics Card and an nVidia 920M. 
When I visit the system details or run "lspci | grep VGA" it detects the Intel Graphics Card. However, in the Additional Drivers setting the 920 is not only the one detected but proprietary drivers are also availabe.
So the questions arising are:

1. If it is only the Intel Integrated graphics running, is there a point in using proprietary nVidia drivers?

   2. How do I make sure the nVidia graphics card runs for Steam Games and the Integrated one runes for all the usual tasks? Is there a programme which lets me choose which one to use in different situations?
      thank you for your time

---

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with your GPU(NVIDIA 920M). If you don't play games, and just browse the internet, type, and listen to music, the Intel Graphics should really be enough. If you play games or use your GPU for complex calculations, CUDA, then you should install it.

Comment: I use my laptop for all the usual stuff but when I have time and I am plugged in I play Steam Games which normally run absolutely fine but are terrible with the Intel graphics. However, I do not want the nVidia card on all the time because it drains battery life. 
Back in windows it automatically understood when the nVidia card had to be enabled.